# C# try finally works differently on different computers

Tags: c#, exception, try-finally

I am trying to run this code in console application to understand how exactly works try-finally

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message");
    throw new Exception("Error");
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Final");
}
```

I tested this on my PC and by notebook, but the results were different. On my notebook I get console output "Message", then error stack trace, then "Final". On my PC the consequence is the same, but without "Final". My notebook is on Windows 11, while my PC is on Windows 10.
NET version is 7.

I am already tryed to run compiled programs in both cases, but that makes no difference.
Also I am not getting "Final" in notebook when run code with debug breaks on every line in Visual Studio 2022.
Any suggestions why this happens and how can I fix/set up the behavior of try finally?.

Comment: I strongly suspect this isn't actually about try/finally, but about how a process ending is shown - and quite possible race conditions between standard output and standard error. Are you able to demonstrate any disparity when *not* letting the process abort?

Comment: What do you mean by not letting the process abort? Should I add a catch block?

Comment: For the purposes of trying to reproduce this *without* it involving the process ending, yes. But it looks like the duplicate probably covers it anyway.

Comment: My guess... you once test it inside visual studio which may block the console window from instant closing, and the other test is you are running the exe directly - add a `Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit"); Console.ReadKey();` at the very end